# getRssi method in wifi info class

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-wireless

In class wifi info the getRssi() method

```
getRssi()
   {
     Return RSSI; 
   }
```

From where they get it? and from where they measure it?
I know RSSI is the signal strength between the access point and the device, but i want to 
understand how they measure it here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is calculated and set in WifiStateMachine's [`fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java#WifiStateMachine.fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative%28%29).
Compilers often have a "Find implementation" or "Find usages" feature which will lead you to the source in many cases. (I used this feature on grepcode.com to find the method above.)